# Starting Activity via Intent is slow / shows considerable delay - why?

Tags: android

I have a very simple MainActivity, and from that Activity I start the other Activity (with theme Dialog so it floats on top of the MainActivity.

The problem is that there is always a delay before the second Activity show up. I'd say it takes almost 1 second for it to show, and there is no code at all in second Activity. The only code in the second Activity is this:

```
package MyPackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class JobViewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jobview);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

The MainActivity has a ListView with Nodes, and there is a click listener connected to the ListView in the onCreate like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _nodeRowAdapter = new NodeRowAdapter(this, _nodes);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewNodes);
    listView.setAdapter(_nodeRowAdapter);   

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JobViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

But when the ListItem is pressed, and the Click listener is triggered, it takes about 1 second to show the "popup".

The layout isn't very advanced in the popup. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" 
  android:stretchColumns="1" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="Id: "
                android:padding="10dip"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Ext id: "
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="10dip" />
        </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#E7F3F1">
             <Button android:text="Start" android:id="@+id/button1" style="@style/ButtonText" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/button_green"></Button>

            <Button android:text="Bom" android:id="@+id/button2" style="@style/ButtonText" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/button_red"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Mer" android:id="@+id/button3" style="@style/ButtonText" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/button_yellow"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Nav" android:id="@+id/button4" style="@style/ButtonText" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:padding="6dip">
        <TextView style="@style/JobViewHeader" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="Something: "></TextView>
        <TextView style="@style/JobViewHeader" android:id="@+id/TextView2" android:text="Something: " android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"></TextView>
        <TextView style="@style/JobViewHeader" android:id="@+id/TextView3" android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:text="Kund: " android:layout_below="@+id/TextView2"></TextView>
        <TextView style="@style/JobViewHeader" android:id="@+id/TextView4" android:text="Something: " android:layout_below="@+id/TextView3"></TextView>
        <TextView style="@style/JobViewHeader" android:id="@+id/TextView5" android:text="Something: " android:layout_below="@+id/TextView4"></TextView>
        <TextView style="@style/JobViewHeader" android:id="@+id/TextView6" android:text="Something: " android:layout_below="@+id/TextView5"></TextView>
        <TextView style="@style/JobViewHeader" android:id="@+id/TextView7" android:text="Something: " android:layout_below="@+id/TextView6"></TextView>
        <TextView style="@style/JobViewHeader" android:id="@+id/TextView8" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:text="Something: " android:layout_below="@+id/TextView7"></TextView>

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" android:id="@+id/textViewPickuptime"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView2" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView2" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView2" android:id="@+id/textViewPickupAddress"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/TextView4" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView3" android:id="@+id/textViewCustomer"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView4" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView4" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView4" android:id="@+id/textViewNbrOfPassengers"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/TextView6" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView5" android:id="@+id/textViewRoutine"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView6" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView6" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView6" android:id="@+id/textViewServiceFee"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView7" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView7" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView7" android:id="@+id/textViewHelp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView8" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView8" android:id="@+id/textViewExtra"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Im not sure what else to tell you, there isnt much more too it.

Im testing on a device, Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: if the JobView is very large in terms of having lots of sub layouts and nested deep, then the inflation time might be a bit. Can't tell if that is the problem though.

Comment: I'd add some logging and make sure where's the delay. It could happen before ``onItemClick`` is called or after you call ``startActivity``. Knowing this could help us understanding the problem.

Comment: @MrJre: I can completely empty the XML (as I mentioned above), so it contains almost nothing. It still lags noticably.

Comment: @MrJre: Ok, its actually faster if I completely remove all XML. I have update with the XML...

Comment: I trust RelativeLayouts with several alignements may be somehow slow

Comment: looking at the XML it should get handled easily, its not that complex. I've seen far worse :) There are optimizations you can do ofcourse, its not nesc to put 4 buttons in a linear layout into a relative layout for example, and relative layouts within relative layouts is not really needed either. I get why you want to do so because it is convenient, but it also slows things down a bit because it actually makes those Views; one of the downsides of this system.

Comment: Layout using XML is messy, it behaves unpredictable I think. I had the same problem when I was/am using ext.net, ie web development. There u also define layout in markup, and its really hard to know what attrbutes to use when, what controls to nest inside another control to get the desired behaviour. The best design thing I have ever seen is DevExpress LayoutControl for .NET - thats easy and just great =)